# Emacs showing slightly different color under text than background?

Tags: emacs

This is subtle, but emacs is showing a slightly different color under any text/actual whitespace than the blank areas in the background.  It's *very* mild but annoying now that I can see it.  Does anyone know what might cause this or how I can debug it?  This is in an X11 frame on Mint 19.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you do `describe-face` or `describe-char` in the different regions?  I notice that in a `#define`, there's an extra `c-in-sws` text property.

Comment: Compare the background attribute of face `default` with the frame's `background-color` frame parameter. Use `customize-face` for the former and `M-: (frame-parameters nil 'background-color)` for the latter.

Comment: @jpkotta I can't describe-face on the empty region because it's literally nothing, can't move the point there =D

Comment: @Drew background of default is #161616 which is right.  frame-parameters also shows #161616

Comment: In that case, try `C-u C-x =` to see if there might be an overlay with a different background. You somehow have different backgrounds for (1) some face (perhaps it's not `default`) and (2) the frame itself (which should, in recent Emacs's, be the same as the background of face `default`).

Comment: @Drew [here's](https://pastebin.com/GykCEbZ7) a paste of C-u C-x = with the point in one of the lighter regions.  I don't see anything to indicate an extra layer, but maybe you'll spot something...